# subprocess, cannot concatenate 'str' and ... objects

Tags: python, shell

I have code like:

```
if len(sys.argv)>1:
    host = sys.argv[1]
    number = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv)>2 else "1"
    size = sys.argv[3] if len(sys.argv)>3 else "56"
    timeout = sys.argv[4] if len(sys.argv)>4 else "1"

        proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping \"" + host + "\" -c \"" + number + "\" -s \"" + size + "\" -W \"" + timeout + "\" 2>/dev/null | grep packets | sed 's/[^0-9,%]*//g'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        (out, err) = proc.communicate()

    print "address=\"" + host + "\" data=" + out
```

I need to split out to list. How I can achieve this?
Everything I try causes error: `cannot concatenate 'str' and ... objects`

Like when I tried:

```
...
    res=list(out)
        print "address=\"" + host + "\" data=" + res
```

I got error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unite strings and lists you first must make a string out of the list:

```
    res=list(out)
    print "address=\"" + str(host) + "\" data=" + str(res)
```